# Remove absolute path from file with bash

Tags: bash

I have file "list.txt" containing absolute paths to other files

```
/home/lin/bash/aaa
/home/lin/bash/song.mp3
/home/lin/bash/doc.html
/home/lin/bash/directory
```

I want to assign path to variable

```
path="/home/lin/bash/song.mp3"
```

and then remove whole line with that path. I've tried

```
sed -i '$path' list.txt
```

and many other command with grep, echo but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your solution. First since you're using single quotes for `'$path'` this expression is treated literally, and not like the variable `$path`. In order to solve this use double quotes `"$path"`. But then you will face the second problem: you want to use slash `/` as a special `sed`-symbol and at the same time this symbol is present in paths, which will confuse `sed`. Therefore you have to use some other symbol instead of slash, for example, use comma

```
$ sed -i "s,${path},," list.txt
$ cat list.txt
/home/lin/bash/aaa

/home/lin/bash/doc.html
/home/lin/bash/directory
```

There is another beautiful approach, suggested by Tim Kennedy (see explanation of how it works in the discussion below), which does not leave the blank line

```
$ sed -i "\,${path},d" list.txt
$ cat list.txt
/home/lin/bash/aaa
/home/lin/bash/doc.html
/home/lin/bash/directory
```

Comment: `sed -i "\#${tmppath}#d" list.txt` will do the same without leaving behind that empty line.

Comment: @Tim, beautiful solution, but I do not understand how it works)) p.s. if you do not mind, I will cite you in my answer.

Comment: Your solution, `"s,${tmppath},,"` is a sed substitution command.  Using a pattern like `/pattern/d` tells sed to delete the line the pattern is in.  Except, in this case, as you rightly pointed out, the delimiter needs to change because the pattern is full of `/` characters.  I should have used commas in my example to make it more similar to yours, so it would be: `"\,${tmppath},d"`.    In a nut shell, the delimiters identify the pattern to find, and the `d` is the delete command.  And the leading backslash tells sed to ignore the `,` as a comma and use it as a delimiter.

Comment: Thank you all for answers. Solution suggested by Tim Kennedy looks the easiest for me.

Comment: @MikeNaplet good reason to upvote his comments)

Answer (score 2):

Try **`grep`** approach once again - it'll work:

```
grep -xv "$path" list.txt > tmp_$$ && mv tmp_$$ list.txt
```

The final `list.txt` contents:

```
/home/lin/bash/aaa
/home/lin/bash/doc.html
/home/lin/bash/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with GNU `sed` and double qoutes to expand the variable.

```
sed -i.bak "\:^${path}$:d" list.txt
```

- Here we used `-i` to have in-place replace/deletion of matched patters as in `$path`, the `.bak` is taking a backup of original `list.txt` file with to `list.txt.bak`
- We used different separator to prevent failing `sed` with slashes `/` in `$path` will contain.
- We used start of line `^` and end of line `$` anchors to match the path in whole line not partially if matched.
- We escaped opening first delimiter as it's mandatory when delimiter is other than slash `/`. in `man sed` documented.

  ```
  \cregexpc
      Match lines matching the regular expression regexp.
      The c may be any character.
  ```

  actually this is telling `sed` that next character is our *delimiter*.